# JavaScript Ajax calls using YUI

Tags: javascript, ajax, yui

Does anybody know if the order of linked external JavaScript files ever matters?. I've never known so but with YUI it seems to be the case when linking library files.

I am making HTTP get Ajax requests, using YUI and I have this HTML file and these 4 files linked (last is my Ajax file and the first 3 are library files from the framework downloaded from the build folder)...

```
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Ajax get page with YUI........</title>

    <script src="yahoo-min.js"></script>
    <script src="event-min.js"></script> 
    <script src="connection-min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>  

  </head>

  <body>

  <h3>Mike's Wednesday Ajax get page........</h3>

      <div id="info">
    This text will be replaced by Ajax dynamically........
  </div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

If I link the library files in any other order, the call fails and I get errors. I'm just wondering as new to Ajax and YUI and as I've said, I've never experienced this before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using YUI3, which makes this all substantially easier. You simply need to load the YUI seed file from the Yahoo! CDN and go from there. Take a look at http://yuilibrary.com/

Comment: Yeah thanks I'll take a look but looks a lot more complex than what I've been used to.

Answer (score 3):

If you stick with YUI 2, I would advice you to use the dependency configurator there: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/hosting/

It will tell you what files to include and in what order.

Comment: I suppose I'd better look at 3 but to be honest, I've spent some time learning what I have and 3 looks complex on first look.

Comment: I can only agree with you, go use YUI3!